# MySqli php UUID_SHORT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Basically what I want to do is to use MySqli to just do a query `UUID_SHORT()` and get the result. No `INSERT`,`UPDATE`,`DELETE` or anything, I just want the value of `UUID_SHORT`.

Haven't been able to figure it out, any help would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `SELECT UUID_SHORT();`

There is more information in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short).

**Example:**

```
function UUID_SHORT(mysqli $db)
{
    $result = $db->query("SELECT UUID_SHORT();");
    $res = $result->fetch_array();
    return $res[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can expand function created by @competent_tech to add more flexibility:

**Example:**

```
function getUuid(mysqli $db, $short=false)
{
    $query = "SELECT " . ($short ? "UUID_SHORT()" : "UUID()");
    $result = $db->query($query)->fetch_array();
    return $result[0];
}
```